# Can I add new and custom fonts to Foxit PDF Editor?

Tags: pdf, fonts, import, foxit-reader, embedded-fonts

We are considering purchasing Foxit PDF Editor for our business (multi-user). However, our brand uses fonts such a Nudista that are not on Foxit. Is it possible to easily import Nudista and other fonts to Foxit so that any editing that we do is compatible with our brand's standard fonts? I can't find anything on the Foxit user guides etc that confirms that this can be done an/or how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you ask Foxit Support? Especially as this is a commercial question.

Comment: That was the first think I tried. Unfortunately FOXIT does not seem to have any 'real people' support; all their responses to my questions came from a BOT referring me to sometimes irrelevant threads. I've spent hours trying to answer this - ideally/logically it should have been in their online user manual 'cos I would have thought it was a top user request? So I'm stumped and may now have to look at Adobe instead.... :(

Comment: Fonts are not installed in a specific program, but on your Operating System. Afterwards, they are available in any program. This does not depend on the specific Editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to Windows, all fonts installed on your machine should be available within Foxit PDF Editor.

Comment: Nudista isn't a Windows font. I want to buy it and install it on Foxit - but have no idea if/how this is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In your case, all you need to do is download a font, select the font file, and drag it over to the Windows font screen. Within a few seconds, you'll have a new font without worrying about restarting your computer or downloading any programs.

If you were looking for a more affordable PDF editor alternative, [SwifDoo PDF](https://www.swifdoo.com) is a must-have.

I hope my answer comes in handy for you.

*I am not affiliated, authorized, endorsed by, or in any way officially connected with the SwifDoo PDF, or any of its subsidiaries or its affiliates.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).